# how I can use std::cin.getline() with string

Tags: c++, string

I have a question about strings in c++

I want to read from user 22 character and store them in string

I tried:

```
std::string name;
std::cin.getline(name,23);
```

it shows an error.

what is the solution to use cin.getline with string ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use [`std::getline(std::istream&, std::string&)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) from `<string>` instead.

If you want to limit things to 22 characters, you can use `std::string` just as you would pass it to any C-style API:

```
std::string example;
example.resize(22); // Ensure the string has 22 slots
stream.getline(&example[0], 22); // Pass a pointer to the string's first char
example.resize(stream.gcount()); // Shrink the string to the actual read size.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two different `getline` functions. One is a member of the istream class, roughly like this:

```
std::istream &std::istream::getline(char *buffer, size_t buffer_size);
```

The other is a free function, something like this:

```
std::istream &std::getline(std::istream &, std::string &);
```

You're trying to call the former, but really want the latter.

Although I don't believe the former is officially deprecated, I suspect most C++ programmers who really keep up on their "game" would consider it about that way -- for backward compatibility it probably can't be removed, but chances are pretty good that you should never use it.

Answer (score 1):

This code reads 22 characters and puts them in a string.

```
char buf[22];
cin.read(buf, 22);
string str(buf, 22);
```

If that is really what you want then this is the code.